# web3j command-line does not recognize flags

Tags: web3j, java, command-line

I am trying to run the command such as

```
web3j solidity generate -b SimpleBank/SimpleBank.bin -a SimpleBank/SimpleBank.abi -o ~/IdeaProjects/quiknode/src/main/java/ -p com.simplebank
```

Found here: https://blog.quiknode.io/web3j-ethereum-for-java-developers/

However, the web3j says :

```
Unknown opitions: -b, ...
```

Version is 1.4.1

Also, their docs of wrappers forward to a 404 page.
At this point, coding a wrapper by hand looks like the best option.

Edit: for the purpose of a code generating, I took the Java source-code for web3j/codegen and ran it against my own .abi and .bin files. However, since this post is about the command line interface, this is not the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in the latest release of [web3j-cli](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-cli) `1.4.1`, the commands were rearranged and the `solidity` wrappers generator command is now under `generate` subcommand.

Run the following for it to work:

```
web3j generate solidity -b SimpleBank/SimpleBank.bin -a SimpleBank/SimpleBank.abi -o ~/IdeaProjects/quiknode/src/main/java/ -p com.simplebank
```

You can also check the other available generators using:

```
web3j generate help
```